# GET request to the API doesnt get any value even though the http path is good

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, get, maui

I want to make a project where i have an ASP.NET server side and i make http requests to the API from my MAUI app.
Today i ran into a huge problem because i just cant get any value from the http requests.
What really annoys me that it worked past week.
I made sure that:

- ASP.NET Swagger UI can make the get request
- My http path is correct, the browser will display the json value for the following address: "https://localhost:5001/api/User"
- In case the problem would be somewhere else in my program i inserted a breakpoint where i make the API call. The program get there, but the value of the variable remains null.
- I currently want to make it work in Windows, I know in android the localhost address is not like this

Here is my (currently pretty simple) RestService class:

```
public class RestService
{
    private HttpClient client;
    public RestService()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
    }


    public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        // The value of the json variable will have null
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/User");
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);

        return user;
    }
```

And this is what is on my ASP.NET side:

The controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<User>))]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    var users =  _userInterface.GetUsers();

    return Ok(users);
}
```

The "Repository" method:

```
public ICollection<User> GetUsers()
{
    return _dataContext.Users.ToList();
}
```

If i dont insert a breakpoint, the application will freeze. So it seems like the GET request not only doesnt return anything, but for some reason it kills the whole app.
This was also not a problem last time.

Comment: it sounds like a timeout.  Put some exception handling around the Get request and wait to see if it catches it.

Comment: If it worked last week, what exactly changed since then? If you revert to a commit from last week, does it start working again?

Comment: I'd also recommend to have the HttpClient injected by DI.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
When i called this method i wanted to get the Result of the task.
Now that i call it in the following way it works:

```
public List<User> Users { get; set; } // changed it from Task<List<User>>
Users = await restService.GetUsersAsnyc(Email,Password);
// changed it from Users = restService.GetUsersAsnyc(Email,Password).Result;
```

I dont know in what scenario i could handle and deal with the Task.Result but now it just froze the whole application.

Comment: you should generally always use `await` when calling an `async` method